# unable to find the select element using jquery present inside a div?

Tags: html, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, parent

i am having the following html markup. upon the `dropdown` change of a `select element (project_dp)`, then i am fetching the parent `div`. and after getting the `parent div` i am fetching the `next div` of this `parent div`. after that when i try to use `find` method to get the `select element(task)` present inside this div, then i am getting nothing.

```
<div class="div_cell">
    <select class="form-control project_dp" id="log_time_project_id" name="log_time[project_id]" onchange="populate_tasks($(this))">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option disabled="true" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
      <option value="18">akjsda</option>
      <option value="19">approval process and approvers save test</option>
      <option value="39">billable test</option></select>
</div>
<div class="div_cell">
    <select class="form-control task" id="log_time_task_id" name="log_time[task_id]"></select>
</div>
```

and the jquery logic

```
function populate_tasks(project_dp) {

   div_node = project_dp.parent();

   next_div = project_dp.parent().next( "div" ).find("select.task");
   alert(next_div.html()); // giving nothing.
}
```

but i am unable to get the `element(select.task)` present in the `next_div`. when i use `alert` statement to see the `html`, then its returning nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its expected result.**, [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html1) get the content of the matched element.

You are getting *nothing* since the `select.task` element is *empty* as it has no child element.

As per comment, If you want to populate it. Use following

```
next_div.append($('<option />', {text: 'SomeText', value:'SomeValue'}))
```

Comment: ok, i want go get this element and i want to populate this empty dropdown with some options. how can i do this using jquery? some sample code i want.